# Get back to top of page with a smooth scrolling and anchor name into URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I used the following code from [this link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/) to have a smooth scrolling page and a callback that makes appears the name of the anchor once scrolling is done (I am calling the callback of .animate):

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        var hash = this.hash; // 'this' will not be in scope in callback
      $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: target.offset().top - 55}, 300, function() {
        location.hash = hash;
        }); 
      return false;
      }   
      }   
      }); 

    //Executed on page load with URL containing an anchor tag.
    if($(location.href.split("#")[1])) {
    var target = $('#'+location.href.split("#")[1]);
    if (target.length) {
      var hash = this.hash; // 'this' will not be in scope in callback
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: target.offset().top - 55}, 300, function() {
      location.hash = hash;
      }); 
    return false;
}
}
});
```

My issue is that I don't know how to be able to return to the top of page when I click on the back button of browser, i.e return to the previous state. For example, first I am on a page (http://example.com/index.html), then I click on an anchor, I am scrolling down to the anchor and after the anchor name is set into URL(http://example.com/index.htm#anchor). But if I click on the back button of browser, I would like to be redirected to the top of page. For the moment, with above script, nothing happens.

### Update

Following Matthew Lymer's answer, I made tests by adding:

```
$(document).ready(function(event) {
      var target = window.location.href.split("#")[1];
      if (target.length) {
        var hash = this.hash; // 'this' will not be in scope in callback
      $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: target.offset().top}, 300, function() {
        location.hash = hash;
        });
      return false;
      }
```

but the animate scrolling to the top of page (wanted when I press back button) doesn't work.

Console prints:

```
  Type Error: target is undefined
```

Comment: What is the HTML of the button?

Comment: the button is the back button of my browser

Comment: Take a look at this function `popstate`, it executes when the URL changes. [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/popstate)

Answer (score 0):

Just reuse your function, but instead of onclick, trigger it to just happen when the document is ready;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ... 
});
```

Instead of setting the value of target to be $(this).hash, take the hash part of the URL using

```
target = window.location.href.split("#");
target = target[1];
```

Comment: thanks, could you put a code snippet please, I am not a jquery expert